# Trouble passing context to helper class method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-toast

Not entirely sure if I'm using those terms (context, helper class) correctly, so excuse me if I'm not.

Anyway, my issue is that I have a class chessboard which needs to call a method in another class, this being the class for the 'knight' piece. The method in this knight class generates a list of possible moves that the knight could make given its current position on the chessboard.

Once the 'possibleMoves' method (located in the knight class) is called, I want it to generate a Toast that will be displayed. However I'm having trouble filling the Toast with a context to use. I'm not sure how to pass the context of the chessboard to the knight class when it's called.

I hope that makes sense.

My code is below -

chessboard portion:

```
final ImageView s01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s01);
        s01.setClickable(true);
        s01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (s01.getDrawable() != (null)) {
                        String Piece = s01.getTag().toString();

                        switch (Piece) {
                            case "black_knight":
                                knight blackKnight = new knight();
                                blackKnight.possibleMoves(0, 1);
                                break;

                        }

                        }


                    }
                });
```

knight class:

```
public class knight extends piece {
    static String chessBoard[][] = chessboard.chessBoard;
    //private static Context boardContext;
    @Override
    public String possibleMoves(int r, int c) {
        String list="", oldPieceRecord;

        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
            for (int k=-1; k<=1; k+=2) {
                try {
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2].charAt(0)) || " ".equals(chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2])) {
                        oldPieceRecord=chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2]="k";
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r+j)+(c+k*2)+oldPieceRecord+(oldPieceRecord.equals(" ") ? "": " ");
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="k";
                        chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2]=oldPieceRecord;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                try {
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k].charAt(0)) || " ".equals(chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k])) {
                        oldPieceRecord=chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k]="k";
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r+j*2)+(c+k)+oldPieceRecord;
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="k";
                        chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k]=oldPieceRecord;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText( ,list, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return list;
    }
```

I understand that some context indicator should go before the comma in the Toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require a Context object in the constructor:

```
private Context mContext;
public knight(Context context)
{
   mContext=context;
   super();
}
...
Toast.makeText(mContext ,list, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

As was said in the comments by peace walker and codeMagic, you can instantiate this object like so:

In a Fragment:

```
knight blackKnight = new knight(getActivity());
```

In an Activity :

```
knight blackKnight = new knight(ChessboardActivity.this);
```

or

```
knight blackKnight = new knight(View.getContext());
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. To add to your answer, the OP could also create the object like this: knight blackKnight = new knight(getActivity());

Comment: @peacewalker good add on and correct assuming it's in a fragment. Otherwise, the OP should pass `v.getContext()` or `ChessboardActivity,this`. I would also suggest to the OP to use proper Java standards and name class names with an uppercase. So, `piece` would be `Piece`. And `knight` would be `Knight`. donquixote, you may want to add these suggestions to your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: don, `this` wouldn't work because that would refer to the `OnClickListener` here. And you would need the `View` object passed to `onClick()` instead of the `View` class so `v.getContext()` in this scenario.

Comment: thank you, this did exactly what I've been trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Hope i can help you (i don't know english). 
  You can create constructor of class knight like this.

```
 public class knight extends piece {
static String chessBoard[][] = chessboard.chessBoard;
private Context mContext;
public knight(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;       
}
// your code
```

}

and :

```
knight blackKnight = new knight(yourContext);
```

Now you can use context in your class.